# How to avoid converting long number to scientific notation?

Tags: python, csv, formatting, cgi

I have list of list which I am writing to a csv file, there is one value in the list which is number(>20 digits) is getting converted to scientific notation. The list is composed of missed types(int/string/float)

Eg:

```
[["Number", "Value", "Category"],
[1498780296322806, 23.4453, 'AAA']]

import csv,sys
csv.writer(sys.stdout,delimiter=",").writerows(export_to_file_contents)
```

Can some one tell me how do I avoid this conversion ? I tried str(1498780296322806) when appending to list but still the csv has the scientific notation.